# How to patsubst multiple paths in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have defined a list of paths

```
paths = /src/nam1 /src/name2
```

And I'm trying to replace each of them with multiple paths like this

```
/src/nam1 -> /dist/nam1.foo /dist/nam1.bar
/src/nam2 -> /dist/nam2.foo /dist/nam2.bar
```

`patsubst` only allows me do to a 1:1 mapping

```
$(patsubst src/%,dist/%.foo,$(paths))
```

Is it possible to also do the mapping for `.bar` without repeating the whole thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
$(foreach x,foo bar,$(patsubst src/%,dist/%.$(x),$(paths)))
```